# Get milliseconds from timer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run app with node.js which would show how much time left until the event will end. So far I can get how many: hours, minutes, seconds left but I need milliseconds as well.

```
    var lottery_data = {
    start: 0,
    endTime: 0,
    running: 0,
    roundTime: (86400 * 1000)
};

/**
 * Start the lottery
 */

lottery();

/**
 * Lottery functions and methods
 */

function lottery() {
    var functionData = {
        timeLeft: 0,
        timeLeftDetails: {
            msAll: 0,
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            ms: 0
        }
    };

    // check for start time and define if not defined
    if (lottery_data.start == 0) {
        lottery_data.start = Math.floor(Date.now());
        lottery_data.endTime = Math.floor(Date.now()) + lottery_data.roundTime;
    }

    // how much time left to end?
    if (lottery_data.running == 0) {
        functionData.timeLeft = lottery_data.endTime - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // seconds
        if (functionData.timeLeft > 1) {
            lottery_data.running = 0;

            // construct time left
            functionData.timeLeftDetails.msAll = lottery_data.endTime - Math.floor(Date.now());
            functionData.timeLeftDetails.hours = parseInt((functionData.timeLeftDetails.msAll / 3600) / 1000);
            functionData.timeLeftDetails.minutes = parseInt(((functionData.timeLeftDetails.msAll / 1000) - (functionData.timeLeftDetails.hours * 3600)) / 60);
            functionData.timeLeftDetails.seconds = parseInt(((functionData.timeLeftDetails.msAll / 1000) - (functionData.timeLeftDetails.hours * 3600)) - (functionData.timeLeftDetails.minutes * 60));

            console.log('Left hours: ' + functionData.timeLeftDetails.hours + ', mins: '
                + functionData.timeLeftDetails.minutes + ', seconds: ' + functionData.timeLeftDetails.seconds
                + ', ms: ' + functionData.timeLeftDetails.ms + ', msAll: ' + functionData.timeLeftDetails.msAll);

            // call function itself
            setTimeout(lottery, 10);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('lottery running!');
    }
}
```

so with this I can see stuff: http://pastebin.com/tYMSSUMx

but how to know how many ms left? I tried to take the hours+minutes+seconds amount from all ms count but it didn't helped.

Comment: Don't you already solve this in your code? `functionData.timeLeft = lottery_data.endTime - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // seconds`

Comment: `Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since midnight, 1/1/1970 UTC, which is apparent from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Comment: So follow the pattern like the hours, minutes, seconds did...

Comment: @WesFoster yup but this shows how much MS left at all. I need the count after hours, minutes and seconds. Only how much miliseconds left until the next second will start.

Comment: Just remove the part where you divide by 1000: `functionData.timeLeft = lottery_data.endTime - Math.floor(Date.now())`

Comment: @epascarello if i knew the answer i wouldn't asked it here. I tried it and I failed it, so I came here.

Comment: @WesFoster as I said before I don't need to know how many ms left at all... I need to know how many MS left until the next second will start..

Comment: Look at what seconds did, it subtracted out the remainders hours and minutes. So you should add one more that subtracts out the remainder of hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: @epascarello could you just type it? because as i said - i tried and it didn't worked for me?